# 3-Legged Token for Forge Application

Tags: autodesk-forge

Im trying to get a 3-Legged Token with Authorization Code Grant:
https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/oauth/v2/tutorials/get-3-legged-token/#step-3-exchange-the-authorization-code-for-an-access-token

I managed to get my token in the URL like the tutorial says in step 2:
[Redirected URL to get the Token](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gFmiN.png)

Its also no problem to extract it out of the URL.
But my problem is, that when I step back to my index.html of my application the token is not valid anymore.(I think it refresh already)

How can I step to my application after getting the token?

[URL of my App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CAIRI.png)

Thanks!

Comment: Ok I could fix it. Thank you anyway.

Comment: glad it's working now, can you please share what was wrong?